# Using AVKit to detect luminosity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, delegates

I am working on an app using SwiftUi that leverages the device camera to detect luminosity as described in top answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921326/how-to-get-light-value-from-avfoundation/46842115#46842115). The `captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:)` function in the top answer was used to calculate luminosity. According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput) this function is intended to notify a delegate that a new video frame was written, and so I have placed this function in a `VideoDelegate` class. This delegate is then set in a `VideoStream` class that handles the logic of asking permissions and setting up an `AVCaptureSession`. My question is how to access the `luminosity` value calculated within the delegate inside my SwiftUI view?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var videoStream = VideoStream()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(videoStream.luminosityReading) ?? Detecting...")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

```
class VideoStream: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var luminosityReading : Double = 0.0 // TODO get luminosity from VideoDelegate
    var session : AVCaptureSession!
    
    init() {
        authorizeCapture()
    }
    
    func authorizeCapture() {
        // permission logic and call to beginCapture()
    }
    
    func beginCapture() {        
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        let videoDevice = bestDevice() // func definition omitted for readability 
        guard
            let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice),
            session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput)
        else {
            print("Camera selection failed")
            return
        }
        
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        guard
            session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        else {
            print("Error creating video output")
            return
        }
        
        session.sessionPreset = .high
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoFrameQueue")
        let delegate = VideoDelegate()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(delegate, queue: queue)
        
        session.commitConfiguration()
        session.startRunning()
    }
}
```

```
class VideoDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        //Retrieving EXIF data of camara frame buffer
        let rawMetadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(allocator: nil, target: sampleBuffer, attachmentMode: CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate))
        let metadata = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, rawMetadata) as NSMutableDictionary
        let exifData = metadata.value(forKey: "{Exif}") as? NSMutableDictionary
        
        let FNumber : Double = exifData?["FNumber"] as! Double
        let ExposureTime : Double = exifData?["ExposureTime"] as! Double
        let ISOSpeedRatingsArray = exifData!["ISOSpeedRatings"] as? NSArray
        let ISOSpeedRatings : Double = ISOSpeedRatingsArray![0] as! Double
        let CalibrationConstant : Double = 50
        
        //Calculating the luminosity
        let luminosity : Double = (CalibrationConstant * FNumber * FNumber ) / ( ExposureTime * ISOSpeedRatings )
         
        // how to pass value of luminosity to `VideoStream`? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `VideoDelegate` *have to* be a separate class? Why not make `VideoStream` conform to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and implement the delegate method there?

Comment: This is a great solution, I've gotten the app running but unfortunately `luminosityReading` is not changing.

Comment: Did you set it anywhere? Did you use the debugger to see what is getting called?

Comment: Yes I've now set `delegate = self` and added a print statement to `captureOutput` and have determined it is never being called. Updated code is at https://github.com/harr1424/LibreLightSensor/blob/main/LibreLightSensor/ContentView.swift.  this seems to be a common problem with a known solution force unwrapping the parameters for `captureOutput` but this also has not resulted in the function being called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999250/captureoutput-not-being-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the lowest friction option would be to have `VideoStream` conform to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and implement the delegate method there.